# How to wrap words to look like tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to listen to input and when space is clicked with javascript, the word that is before the space, will be wrapped to look like a tag.

It should be like the "Tags" below in the "Ask a public question".
code so far:

html:

```html
<label for="subtypes" id="subtypes_label"><b>Restaurant subtypes</b></label>
<textarea type="text" name="subtypes" class="form-control w-50 p-3" id="subtypes" autocomplete="off" oninput=""></textarea>
```

javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('subtypes').addEventListener('input', function(evt){
    wrapSubtypes(this.value);
});
function wrapSubtypes(value){

}
```

I don't know what to put in the `wrapSubtypes(value)`.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add a bespoke class to the element and style with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want to return a wrapped text in an element from the function like:

```
return `<span class="tag">${value.trim().split(/\s/).pop()}</span>`
```

```js
document.getElementById('subtypes').addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  if (evt.data === ' ') {
    let tag = wrapSubtypes(this.value);
    document.getElementById('tags').innerHTML += tag;
  }
});

function wrapSubtypes(value) {
  return `<span class="tag">${value.trim().split(/\s/).pop()}</span>`
}
```

```css
#tags{ padding:10px; }

.tag {
  border-radius: 25%;
  color: #444;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  padding:5px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div><label for="subtypes" id="subtypes_label"><b>Restaurant subtypes</b></label>
<textarea type="text" name="subtypes" class="form-control w-50 p-3" id="subtypes" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="tags"></div>
```

Comment: It works fine but how do I insert the styled tag into the text area?

Comment: You can't but you can style/mock them to place over the text area. It needs some calculations of offsets. There you can place it over text area. also in that case you need to shorten the text area too.

Comment: I'll think about a way to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
document.getElementById('subtypes').addEventListener('input', function(evt){
    wrapSubtypes(this.value);
});
function wrapSubtypes(value){
  if(value.includes(' ')) {
    let newElement = `<li>${value.trim()}</li>`;
    document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML += newElement
    document.getElementById('subtypes').value = ""
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="subtypes" id="subtypes_label"><b>Restaurant subtypes</b></label><br>
<textarea type="text" name="subtypes" class="form-control w-50 p-3" id="subtypes" autocomplete="off" oninput=""></textarea>

<p>Tags:</p>
<ul>
</ul>
```